# Match string between two colons in multiline string

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, tidyr, stringr

I am using `stringr` to extract the date and the train identifier for each row in a dataframe from the variable `status`. The string should have the following format:

```
2008-07-01 : Train_528 :cancelled
2005-11-01 : Train_528 :postponed
2005-06-28 : Train_528 :ontime
```

I use the following code to extract train id and date:

```
train_df %>% 
  separate_rows(status, sep = "\\n") %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(str_extract(status, "\\d.*\\d")),
         train_id = str_extract(status, "(?<=:)\\w.*(?= :ontime)"))
```

The code works successfully. However, in some cases, the data is formatted incorrectly where the train ID should have been between the date and the status.

```
2008-07-01 : :cancelled
2005-11-01 : :postponed
2005-06-28 : :ontime
 :Train_528 :cancelled
 :Train_528 :postponed
 :Train_528 :ontime
```

The main way to identify this issue is to match two colons with no characters in between:`": :"`. What pattern can I use to pull the train ID without matching the train status string.

I tried using the following code but failed:

```
train_df %>% 
  separate_rows(status, sep = "\\n") %>%
  mutate(status_duplicated = status) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(str_extract(status, "\\d.*\\d")),
         train_id = if_else(str_detect(status, ":\\s:"), 
                            str_extract(status_duplicated, "(?<=:)\\w.*(?= :ontime)"),
                            str_extract(status, "(?<=:)\\w.*(?= :)")))
```

##### Reprex:

```r
train_df <- structure(list(county = 1:3, status = c("2008-07-01 : :cancelled\n2005-11-01 : :postponed\n2005-06-28 : :ontime\n :Train_528 :cancelled\n :Train_528 :postponed\n :Train_528 :ontime", 
"2017-01-13 :Train_222 :ontime\n2016-09-30 :Train_222 :postponed\n2016-09-14 :Train_222 :cancelled\n2014-08-07 :TR 1323 :cancelled\n :TR 1323 :postponed", 
"1985-05-18 :Train_12 :ontime\n1981-12-15 :Train_12 :postponed"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: In the case of incorrect foramt, what's your expected output? It looks like that the train ID are missing in the first 3 rows and the dates are missing in the last 3 rows, right?

Comment: I am using the same example twice to demonstrate how the format changes. Expected output is: data:train_id:status. But the aim is really to extract the train_id if the :  : is present.

Comment: It's still not clear. Could you provide reproducible example to your post? You could copy/paste the output of `dput(train_df)` to your post. If `train_df` is large, don't pass it to `dput` entirely. Just keep the key rows e.g. `dput(train_df[1:3, ])`.

Comment: There must a more elegant way without so many lines of code and complicated regex syntax. If you want to learn more, you need to edit your post to include reproducible example data, and there might be some experienced users willing to help you.

Comment: Added a small dataframe to test using the dput function. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected outcome is implicit. Here is a possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

train_df %>%
  separate_rows(status, sep = "\n") %>%
  separate(status, c("date", "train_id", "status"), sep = "\\s*:\\s*") %>%
  mutate(across(-county, na_if, "")) %>%
  fill(date, train_id, .direction = "downup")

# A tibble: 13 × 4
   county date       train_id  status   
    <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    
 1      1 2008-07-01 Train_528 cancelled
 2      1 2005-11-01 Train_528 postponed
 3      1 2005-06-28 Train_528 ontime   
 4      1 2005-06-28 Train_528 cancelled
 5      1 2005-06-28 Train_528 postponed
 6      1 2005-06-28 Train_528 ontime   
 7      2 2017-01-13 Train_222 ontime   
 8      2 2016-09-30 Train_222 postponed
 9      2 2016-09-14 Train_222 cancelled
10      2 2014-08-07 TR 1323   cancelled
11      2 2014-08-07 TR 1323   postponed
12      3 1985-05-18 Train_12  ontime   
13      3 1981-12-15 Train_12  postponed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
train_df %>% 
  mutate(status_duplicated = status) %>% 
  separate_rows(status, sep = "\\n") %>% 
  mutate(date = if_else(str_detect(status_duplicated, "\\d.*\\d : :(ontime|cancelled|postponed)"),
                                 as.Date(str_extract(status_duplicated, "\\d.*\\d(?= : :ontime)")),
                                 as.Date(str_extract(status, "\\d.*\\d"))),
         train_id = if_else(str_detect(status_duplicated, "\\d.*\\d : :(ontime|cancelled|postponed)"), 
                                str_extract(status_duplicated, "(?:(?<= :)\\w.*(?= :ontime))"),
                                str_extract(status, "(?<=:)\\w.*(?= :)"))) %>% 
  unique()

# A tibble: 13 × 4
   county status                             date       train_id 
    <int> <chr>                              <date>     <chr>    
 1      1 "2008-07-01 : :cancelled"          2005-06-28 Train_528
 2      1 "2005-11-01 : :postponed"          2005-06-28 Train_528
 3      1 "2005-06-28 : :ontime"             2005-06-28 Train_528
 4      1 " :Train_528 :cancelled"           2005-06-28 Train_528
 5      1 " :Train_528 :postponed"           2005-06-28 Train_528
 6      1 " :Train_528 :ontime"              2005-06-28 Train_528
 7      2 "2017-01-13 :Train_222 :ontime"    2017-01-13 Train_222
 8      2 "2016-09-30 :Train_222 :postponed" 2016-09-30 Train_222
 9      2 "2016-09-14 :Train_222 :cancelled" 2016-09-14 Train_222
10      2 "2014-08-07 :TR 1323 :cancelled"   2014-08-07 TR 1323  
11      2 " :TR 1323 :postponed"             NA         TR 1323  
12      3 "1985-05-18 :Train_12 :ontime"     1985-05-18 Train_12 
13      3 "1981-12-15 :Train_12 :postponed"  1981-12-15 Train_12
```

The issue with this solution is that I have to duplicate the output and remove duplicates using the unique function.

Comment: I add the output to this answer which is produced by your data and code. Could you explain why the all `date` are `2005-06-28` and all `train_id` are `Train_528` for `county=1`?

Comment: Ah, good point. It's because later on in the script I filter out trains that are not ontime, so it is less important in practice. Apologies for the lack of attention.